# Sublime Text adding additional opening tag at the beginning?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, boilerplate

So every time I use html snippet or boiler plate with `<ht + tab or enter` 
I get this extra opening tag? What gives?

`<<!doctype html> <---- whats that additional tag at the beginning?
  <html> 
......
....`

I got emmet installed by the way. Thanks

Comment: Just write `ht + tab or enter`. `<` is not part of the snippet trigger and ST has sometimes a weird behavior at replacing non-word chars like `<`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a snippet. You type `html` (or less), and press `tab`, it'll inserts all this content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>$1</title>
</head>
<body>
$0
</body>
</html>
```

Note that if you repress tab again, it'll go to `$1`, and the last one is `$0` (by default it's the end of the content).

So, don't type `<ht`, just `ht`, `tab`, and it'll insert everything for you. I really recommend you find yourself a course about Sublime Text, you're going to miss so much otherwise

Answer (score 0):

That is the doctype decleration this is straight out of hte W3School docs:

> The  declaration must be the very first thing in your HTML
>   document, before the  tag.
>
> The  declaration is not an HTML tag; it is an instruction to
>   the web browser about what version of HTML the page is written in.
>
> In HTML 4.01, the  declaration refers to a DTD, because HTML
>   4.01 was based on SGML. The DTD specifies the rules for the markup language, so that the browsers render the content correctly.
>
> HTML5 is not based on SGML, and therefore does not require a reference
>   to a DTD.
>
> Tip: Always add the  declaration to your HTML documents, so
>   that the browser knows what type of document to expect.

You can read more about it here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp

Comment: Thats not what I mean, I was referring to the '<<' double tag at the beginning. Its a feature to when you type few letters auto complete will trigger.

Comment: According to the Sublime text package page, that shouldn't be there: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/HTML%20Snippets

Comment: Yes its weird, how do I edit those snippets myself anyways?